# Swift 4, Firebase how to observe the snapshot and convert into object

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase datastructure looks like this:
[image]

user is the parent, underneath it is the user uid and Dream, Grocery list is the note titles and they have their content. I am trying to observe the value of the titles and put them into an array to put in a tableview. This is what I have so far but since the titles of the note are different every time, I dont know how to do a model for that:

```
 DataService.ds.REF_CURRENT_USER.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        for snap in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            print("Note Title:\(snap.key)")
        }
    }
```

This prints out everything including email and provider but I dont want that I just want it to print Dream and Grocery List

Comment: What's stored in the content nodes. It looks like a string but if it's a grocery list that would change the code to read this in. Also, you question states you want to * observe the value of the titles* which is unclear - what titles? Do you mean Dream and Grocery list? Do you want to read it all at one time or separately for two different lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code to get your required values

```
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
        return
    }

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child("\(uid)")
    ref.child("Dream").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] else {
            return
        }
        print(dictionary["content"] as? String)

    }, withCancel: nil)

    ref.child("Grocerylist").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] else {
            return
        }
        print(dictionary["content"] as? String)

    }, withCancel: nil)
```

Comment: Careful with this answer. While it will work ok if the child of content is a string, if it's, for example, a list of groceries that need to stay in order, it wouldn't be the best solution. Also, the GroceryList closure could technically complete before the Dream closure and that may cause issues in the ui. It would be better to observe the whole node once instead of two separate observes.